# SSH to a host and enter password with shell script

Tags: shell, ssh

I want to create a file like this :
sshTOhost :

```
#!bin/bash
ssh -D 1500 user@host
#enter password (I don't know how)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [sshpass](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/noninteractive-shell-script-ssh-password-provider/) to use `ssh` in a shell script; the script can then automatically provide the password to `ssh` by using `sshpass`. The linked article explains how to do this, and also why you absolutely shouldn't do this.

Instead, you should use [public key authentication](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ssh-password-less-login-with-dsa-publickey-authentication/). If you need to automate it completely without any user input, you can set up a private key without passphrase; your script can then use this key to connect to the remote host without any user input.

Answer (score 2):

You have another way:

`expect`  is a command line for your task, at first install it, Then write in your `script`:

```
#!bin/bash
ssh -D 1500 user@host
expect "Echo of after ssh -D 1500 user@host"
send yourpassword\r
wait
```

Of course, It's dangerouse, because everyone can read your password.

Answer (score 0):

I use [expect](http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm) in a script to automate the installation of software on new servers.  It has a bit of a learning curve but once it is set up, it works really well.